# Trying to dismiss UIAlertController iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Crashlytics send me this error in my app:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Trying to dismiss UIAlertController <UIAlertController: 0x14de40020> with unknown presenter.

UIKit   
-[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:] + 584
```

This problem only occurs in iOS 8 but when I try to reproduce this error, my `alertViews` work correctly in iOS 8 and nothing bad happens. Why this problem is happening?

I have read that in iOS 8 `UIAlertView` is deprecated and now, we have to use `UIAlertController` but when I try to use UIAlertController I can't dismiss the alert and the functionality is not the same.

Please help me.

Thank you for advance.

**EDIT:**

The code I want to change is this:

```
UIAlertView * alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: AMLocalizedString(@"alertUpdate", @"")
                                                  message:@"\n"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); // .5 so it doesn't blur
[alerta addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
[alerta show];


UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:dis bundle:nil];
MainVC *main = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: main];
[self presentModalViewController: navControl animated: YES];

[alerta dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace this

```
[self presentModalViewController: navControl animated: YES];
[alerta dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

With this

```
[alerta dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self presentModalViewController: navControl animated: YES];
}];
```

This presents a new controller asynchronously to make sure the alert view is dismissed

Comment: I am told by Xcode that presentModalViewController is deprecated in iOS 6.0, however replacing the line in the block with a different method (I have internal to my project) it worked. Thanks I have up voted the answer. :)

Comment: I know about the deprecation). I just edited the source lines to make the answer more appropriate to the question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you were able to solve this, but I had a similar issue and here is a potential solution:

Implement the **UIAlertViewDelegate Protocol** and override the 
**alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:** method.

Any presenting or dismissing of view controllers should occur **within** this method to be 100% sure that the the AlertView is completely dismissed before we navigate elsewhere and the "presenter" becomes unknown.

You can also do this when navigating from a UIActionSheet button click.

Answer (score 0):

Set `popoverPresentationController` for `UIAlertController`

Use like this code :

```
UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                                                  message: nil
                                                                           preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
        [alertController addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"title" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        }]];
CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
 rect.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width / 20;
 rect.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height / 20;
[alertController.popoverPresentationController setPermittedArrowDirections:0];
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = rect;
[alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
[self presentViewController: alertController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: Is necessary to add an action?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. While the alert is showing I change the view controller and turn back to the mainVC. When I push your code the alert appear but I can't push de mainVC.